# Preserve the last element of a mutable prop React

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an array `arr` from the props of a component, the `props.arr` can change inside `myComponent`, so when `myComponent` first render I want to get the last item of the `arr` and preserve it for later use. What is the best way to achieve that?

```
function myComponent(props: any) {
    // props.arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    const [lastVal, setLastVal] = useState(0);

    // I can do it like that, but want a better solution
    useEffect(() => {
       setLastVal(props.arr[props.arr.length - 1]);
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a *better* solution? Your current one works, right?

Comment: @tdranv yes, but looking for a simpler solution without having to use hooks..

Comment: Well, hooks are at the core of functional components in React nowadays. You may be able to do a workaround via the `localStorage` but the hooks option is much better. Take a look at @Ryan Le's answer for a custom hook solution.

Answer (score 2):

One of a good way is to implement a `usePrevious` hook like so:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

// Refer to the previous value
export function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T | undefined {
  const ref = useRef<T>();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
}
```

This will always return the previous values that you pass to it.